# leaking coolant driver side half way back on engine in 2001 chevy blazer

Tags: chevrolet, blazer, coolant-leak

on the driver side about half way back on engine block coolant pooring onto the ground. I thought it was the lines coming of oil filter that run near tansmission but I took it off that's a oil line not coolant. i didn't see anything coming out top of engine or near heater core. this is not my first rodeo but i don't see no coolant lines on driver side. could it be the intake. where the coolant hits the ground it is like halfway back on the block and its a major amount coming out any ideas

Comment: Do you have any photos? Is it at the top of the block (between block and head), or further down? Are there any distinguishing features that it looks like the coolant is coming from? (for example, a round depression in the side of the block, which will house a core plug)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are correct and their are indeed no coolant lines around there, I can only think of 3 things, but the second 2 are certainly grasping at straws

1. Freeze plug.  Nick C called it a core plug.  If one of those is no longer sealing or is gone completely, you would be pouring coolant and it might be very hard to see.  Feel around for a hole, preferably with the engine off.
2. You've got a tear in a line someplace nearby that is spraying all the way over to the block.  Or the water pump or some other accesory with the same problem.  From the way your question is worded, it sounds like this is not the case.
3. There is a non-factory hole in the side of the block that punches through to a coolant channel.  Maybe it rusted out (somehow), maybe it got shot at, maybe somebody with a drill really hates you.

Comment: The core plug is a remnant from the casting process - it is not designed to save the engine from damage due to freezing : have seen damage that is between , above or next to the plug while the plug is perfect...